# Gravitational force between rod and mass $m$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Why do we integrate along the whole length while finding the gravitational force between a object of mass ($m$) and a rod of length $L$ and mass $M\,?$ Can't we simply use $F=\frac{GmM}{r^2} \, ?$

Comment: Hint: What would you set equal to $r$?

Comment: distance between center of mass of the rod and the mass (m)

Comment: Nope, can't do that. The part of the rod at the CoM, i.e. the mid part of the rod, pulls more than all other parts (assuming the object is in fron the middle of the rod). So, if you say all of its mass is at the CoM, you'd overestimate the gravitational pull. You have to sum the gravitational pull from _all_ its parts, each of which has a different $r$. The smaller the length of the parts is, the more precise your result will be. In the limit where the length of the parts is an infinitesimally small $dr$, this sum is called "the integral".

Comment: You're probably thinking of a sphere, where the gravitational attraction from outside of the sphere acts the same as a point mass at the center of the sphere. The same isn't true for other shapes, not even ellipsoids (as I recently found it when studying "surface normals").

Comment: yes. why don't we integrate in case of sphere but in rod we do even though both have centre of mass given ?

Comment: Because the integral has already been done for the sphere (by Newton, Gauss, others, every student in intermediate mechanics for 200 years), and we know the result.  It reduces to the same as a point mass at the center of the sphere.  The rod integral does *not* reduce to a point mass at the center of the rod because of the non-linear behavior of the force vs linear nature of the mass distribution.

Comment: As @BillN notes, the sphere is a special case that does not apply to other shapes. If you're very far away from an object, you can approximate the gravitational force as coming from its center of mass without too much loss of accuracy. However, that's another special case. Unless the object is a consistently-dense sphere (or spherical shell) or you are far away from it, you can not apply the center of mass simplification.

Answer (score 1):

We have to consider the contribution of each little piece of mass $\mathrm{d}M = \rho \mathrm{d}V$ and how far it is from the other mass, $m$ resulting in a small force $\mathrm{d}F$. If you have uniform distribution of mass, $\rho=M/(LA)$, where $A$ is the cross sectional area of the rod, and we probably don't integrate over that because it's a small diameter rod. So $\mathrm{d}V=A\,\mathrm{d}x$. Then we have a $1/r^2$ force behavior where $r$ is the distance from each $\mathrm{d}M$.
$$\mathrm{d}F=\frac{-Gm}{r^2}\mathrm{d}M=\frac{-Gm}{r^2}\frac{M}{L}\mathrm{d}x$$
  To find $r$, you have to give a specific geometry, and let $x$ be the variable of integration that runs along the length and integrate from $0$ to $L$. $r$ will be a function of $x$. The geometry dictates what that function is. Because of the nature of $1/r^2$, the force does not change linearly, but the distance from rod to mass $m$ *might* (again, the geometry is important).

In your comment, you mentioned the sphere situation. That means that for a sphere of mass $M$ and radius $R_0$ $$\mathrm{d}M=\rho\, \mathrm{d}V = \frac{M}{V_{sp}}R^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}R \,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi $$
$$0<R<R_0$$
where $R$ is a spherical variable of integration, along with $\theta$ and $\phi$. The distance $r$ will be a function of $R$, $\theta$, and $\phi$.  Without going into the details, an examination of the form of $\mathrm{d}M$ shows that the mass is *not* linearly distributed, so there's a chance, at least, that a $1/r^2$ force will reduce to something simple.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer to be helpful, either accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it or give it an upvote.